# django-permission AuthorPermissionLogic not working in function based view

Tags: django, django-permissions

Am using [django-permission](http://django-permission.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on simple test app (almost identical to the example used in the docs) to try to figure out how it works. I have read the documentation and tried to use the example app provided on this [link](https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-permission/issues/28).

The issue is when the author of an article is not able to edit/ delete the article.

The user in question has been granted all permissions in the admin section.

Key code listed below - any help much appreciated

**test_app/models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'test_app'

from permission import add_permission_logic
from permission.logics import AuthorPermissionLogic

add_permission_logic(Article, AuthorPermissionLogic(
    field_name='created_by',
    any_permission = False,
    change_permission = True,
    delete_permission = True,
))
```

**test_app/views.py**

```
@permission_required('change_article')
def change_article(request, *args, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs.pop('pk')
    template = 'test_app/edit.html'
    article = models.Article.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.Article_form(request.POST, instance=article)

        if form.is_valid():
            article = form.save(commit=False)

            article.created_by = request.user
            article.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            article.content = form.cleaned_data['content']

            article.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/test/')

        else:

            raise Http404

    else:
        form = forms.Article_form(instance=article)

        return render(request, template_name=template, context={'form':form})
```

**test_app/perms.py**

```
PERMISSION_LOGICS = (
    ('test_app.Article', AuthorPermissionLogic()),
)
```

**EDIT**

In the end there is a longer discussion on the project Github page available on this [link](https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-permission/issues/81).

While the objective of the question was resolved - it turns out that the function itself is a bit of a legacy function that is prone to unexpected behavior. The advice of the project owner is to use class based views rather than function based views.

Comment: Shouldn't the permission have a prefix, e.g. `@permission_required('testapp.change_article')`?

Comment: Whhhaaat!? That is outrageous :) - yes this solved the issue of the author not being able to edit their own article. However, it seems to allow every other user to edit the article.

Comment: What does your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting look like? Can other users still edit the article if you remove `'permission.backends.PermissionBackend'` from it?

Comment: AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 
    'permission.backends.PermissionBackend',
)

Comment: When I comment out 'permission.backends.PermissionBackend - I get a bunch of errors from django-permission django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "permission.backends.PermissionBackend" is not found in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.
Users require to specify the backend manually to the option.
Users can ignore this exception via setting `False` to `PERMISSION_CHECK_AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

Comment: Have disabled the permissions check as per instruction - so the error has gone away. But it does not change the behavior

Comment: If you can't fix those errors you could try commenting out `'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` instead. It sounds like other users can edit the article because of regular Django permissions assigned through the Django admin, so was just trying to test out that idea.

Comment: Commenting out the 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' results in the user not being able to log in (sorry I am not sure if it is relevant but I have extended the base user with a profile model linked via a foreign key)

Comment: I wasn’t suggesting you commented out ``ModeBackend` permanently, it was just for debugging. But that won’t work if it causes the user to be logged out immediately.

Comment: Please show the permissions for the other users in the Django admin.

Comment: No worries - am happy for the help! Admin permissions are simple enough - have been playing around with 3 users. User 1 has add/edit/delete perms in the admin. User 2 has the same permissions. User 3 has no permissions related to the app (yet is able to edit)

Comment: Note if User 3 is a superuser then they will have all permissions.

Comment: Nope - not a superuser. I am suspecting that the app is not taking any of the permissions into account. I have tried changing the models.py line so that the "change_permission = False," - this does not affect the behavior... grrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get what

> The user in question has been granted all permissions in the admin section.

means (not sure what "admin section" is) but

1. You don't need `perms.py` while you already add a permission logic in your `models.py`.
2. You need to use `test_app.change_article` instead (`<app_label>.<perm>_<model_name>`)

By the way, while you don't need `perms.py` so it's not a matter but the instance of `AuthorPermissionLogic` in `perms.py` is not properly configured while you haven't specified `field_name` there (the default value of `field_name` is `'author'` if you don't specified.) https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-permission/blob/master/src/permission/conf.py#L24

Comment: Thanks Alisue - have posted on the project Github page. Will reference/ link this discussion with that one. https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-permission/issues/81